# React Tabs Lazy Load

Tags: reactjs, tabs, lazy-evaluation

I am a React beginner from jquery.  Let's say I have three tabs. I am looking for a way to lazy-load the 3 tab-contents so that when I click Tab1 the first time, only the tab1 contents will be loaded and stay in the DOM (not the tab2 and tab3 contents).  When I click Tab2, the tab2 contents will then be loaded (not the tab3 contents).  When I click Tab1 again, the original tab1 content will stay there in the DOM without reloading and re-rendering.

This is the code:

```
<div className="tab-content">
  {/* Tab1 */}
  <div hidden={tab1.name !== activeTab ? true : false}>
    <tab1.component />
  </div>
  {/* Tab2 */}
  <div hidden={tab2.name !== activeTab ? true : false}>
    <tab2.component />
  </div>
  {/* Tab3 */}
  <div hidden={tab3.name !== activeTab ? true : false}>
    <tab3.component />
  </div>
</div>
```

It works, but the problem is that all the three components (tab1.component, tab2.component & tab3.component) got loaded at the same time, even the user never clicks tab2 or tab3, causing wasted processing in the server.

Both the contents in tab2 and tab3 require 'expensive' processing at the server, that's why I want to avoid that.

Thank you.

Comment: Check props of each   tab.component .  If some  props or state was changed when you switch tab,  the component will be rerender.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a wrapping component like this:

```
type LazyProps = {
    visible: boolean;
}

function Lazy({visible, children}: PropsWithChildren<LazyProps>) {
    const rendered = useRef(visible);

    if (visible && !rendered.current) {
        rendered.current = true;
    }

    if (!rendered.current)
        return null;

    return <div style={{display: visible ? 'block' : 'none'}}>{children}</div>;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<div className="tab-content">
    <Lazy visible={tab1.name === activeTab}><tab1.component /></Lazy>
    <Lazy visible={tab2.name === activeTab}><tab2.component /></Lazy>
    <Lazy visible={tab3.name === activeTab}><tab3.component /></Lazy>
</div>
```

The idea is to avoid rendering the tab content until `visible` prop becomes `true` the first time. After that `visible` prop only affects the `display` css rule and therefore state of the tabs is kept.

Comment: Thanks, This one actually worked for my use case, where I just wanted to avoid unnecessary render until the the tab is focused.